# How do I read a list of strings from file into a dynamic two-dimensional array and then sort it in C

Tags: c, file, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C and am having difficulty with reading a file of names into a two-dimensional array to then sort. I figure I should be using malloc, but I'm not quite sure if I have to. The following is the code I have right now which reads the file and prints it out but when I go to sort it only sorts one name with some extra characters added to it. If I could get a hand I would appreciate it.

The file just contains a list of names such as:
John
Alex
George
Beasley

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 128 
#define TOT 10 

void selectionSort_str(char arr[][MAX_LEN], int n)
{
    int i, j, min_idx;

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray 
    char minStr[MAX_LEN];
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array 
        int min_idx = i;
        strcpy(minStr, arr[i]);
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            // If min is greater than arr[j] 
            if (strcmp(minStr, arr[j]) > 0)
            {
                // Make arr[j] as minStr and update min_idx 
                strcpy(minStr, arr[j]);
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }

        // Swap the found minimum element with the first element 
        if (min_idx != i)
        {
            char temp[MAX_LEN];
            strcpy(temp, arr[i]); //swap item[pos] and item[i] 
            strcpy(arr[i], arr[min_idx]);
            strcpy(arr[min_idx], temp);
        }
    }
}


int main(void) {
    char line[TOT][MAX_LEN];
    FILE *plist = NULL; 
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int k = sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0]);

    plist = fopen("plist1.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], MAX_LEN, plist)) {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    total = i;

    for(i = 0; i < total; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", line[i]);
    }

    //sort strings
    selectionSort_str(line, k);
    printf("*****Sorted array is: \n"); 
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", line[i]);
    }    



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int k = sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0]);` is the same as `int k = TOT;`

Comment: You pass k to selectionSort_str but that is wrong - you don't want to sort the ENTIRE array - you only want to sort the number of items you read from the file.

Comment: Oh it was my understanding that I do want to sort the entire array as it contains the string of characters, or the names, and nothing else.

Comment: The array is 10 strings long.  The first five entries have names read from the file.  But you don't initialise the other ones so they contain random data.  If you sort all 10 elements you will mix in the uninitialised items.  You only want to sort the elements read from the file.

Comment: OT: regarding: `plist = fopen("plist1.txt", "r");`  When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

you are possibly a victim of stale `\r\n` , this hack below should help

```
while(fgets(line[i], sizeof(line[i]), plist)) {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';

        // these stale '/r' s when used in strcmp will give unwanted results
        // so strip those aswell..
        if( line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] == '\r' )
            line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: The other problem is that if the last line in the file doesn't end with a linefeed then the code to delete it deletes the last character of the name instead.  To deal with both of them possibly appearing or not you can `line[i][strcspn(line[i],"\r\n")] = '\0';`

Comment: The problem with the OPs posted code is the sorting of unused entries in the array of strings, NOT the elimination of the (possible) trailing newline character(s)  So this answer is wrong